# Can Webpack process Django static files (images)?

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, assets

Is it possible to make Webpack to process images used in Django html templates?

My idea was to require all html files and use `html-loader`. But then how to handle Django static path?

```
 <img src="{% static 'assets/images/image.png' %}">
```

Comment: are you looking for configuration of static path in django ?

Comment: I'm looking for webpack configuration, that will 'known' what assets were used in django templates.